# How to change color for selected number in enabled NumberPicker in Android

Tags: android, numberpicker

I want to achieve this effect on MyNumberPicker

[image]

so far I implemented a NumberPicker class and changed several properties, but the interesting part is here:

```
public class NumberPicker extends android.widget.NumberPicker{

    public NumberPicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void addView(View child) {
        super.addView(child);
        updateView(child);
    }

    @Override
    public void addView(View child, int index, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
        super.addView(child, index, params);
        updateView(child);
    }

    @Override
    public void addView(View child, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
        super.addView(child, params);
        updateView(child);
    }

    private void updateView(View view) {
        if(view instanceof EditText){
            ((EditText) view).setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.numberpicker_text_size));
           ((EditText) view).setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorPrimaryDark));

        }
    }
```

but the effect I get is this:

[image]

I get all text in blue (selected, no selected, active, inactive) how to get this blue only on enabled NumberPicker and selected value?

thanks for the support

Comment: There is answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/56677573/10898426 . You can use setOnTouchListener and change numberPicker's EditText's color **to change the only selected number** like your question's first image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `ColorStateList` with your desired attributes. Then apply those to the `EditText`

```
final ColorStateList colors = new ColorStateList(
                new int[][]{
                        new int[]{android.R.attr.state_selected},
                        new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_selected}
                },
                new int[]{selectedColorCode, defaultColor}
        );

((EditText) view).setTextColor(colors);
```

Comment: I used for selectedColorCode and defaultColor colorPrimary and colorPrimaryDark, however I just see colorPrimary applied, so
what's the difference betweeen this and ((EditText) view).setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorPrimary)); I see them both just in colorPrimary